# Using Contains* symbols to create implicitly defined entity classes

Tags: pattern-matching, entity

The following line finds the higher ed institutions in New York without a Carnegie classification:

```
EntityClass["University", {"Province" -> "New York", "Carnegie2005" -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}] //EntityList;
```

However using `ContainsNone` to find the complementary set returns an empty list.

```
EntityClass["University", {"Province" -> "New York", "Carnegie2005" -> ContainsNone[{Missing["NotAvailable"]}]}] //EntityList;
```

I would have assumed this is correct notation based upon the [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0pusz8spnd-nwjvze), so I am wondering if I have misread the documentation or if this is a bug (which may have been around [since 2015](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136144/use-of-containsany-in-entityclass) or earlier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outline**

- **Method 1: FilteredEntityClass**
- **Method 2 : ComplementedEntityClass**

---

I am learning to use entities so thank you for the question. I am not sure why the code in the question does not work. The sections below represent a work around.

The experimental function [`FilteredEntityClass`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilteredEntityClass.html) introduced in 2019 (version 12) was constructed specifically to filter entity classes by applying test functions.

Alternatively as you would like the complement of a class you may consider [`ComplementedEntityClass`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplementedEntityClass.html) which is also experimental  and which I will use in the second method below.

---

#### Method 1: FilteredEntityClass

First let's test that we get the same list where the code works.

**The original code:**

```
missing=EntityClass["University", {"Province" -> "New York", "Carnegie2005" -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}] //EntityList;
```

Next, **the code using `FilteredEntityClass`** :

```
filtered = 
 FilteredEntityClass["University", 
  EntityFunction[e, 
   e["Carnegie2005"] === Missing["NotAvailable"] && 
    e["Province"] == "New York"]]
```

You may check that `filtered==missing`.

Next we **define the complement entity class**:

```
available = 
  FilteredEntityClass["University", 
   EntityFunction[e, 
    Not[e["Carnegie2005"] === Missing["NotAvailable"] ] && 
     e["Province"] == "New York"]];
```

(Note: ⎵=[UnderBracket])

```
available⎵list = available // EntityList;
```

Just to see how much was found:

```
available⎵list // Length
```

309

---

#### Method 2 : ComplementedEntityClass

Defining the class:

```
    class=ComplementedEntityClass[
 EntityClass["University", {"Province" -> "New York"}], 
 EntityClass[
  "University", {"Province" -> "New York", 
   "Carnegie2005" -> Missing["NotAvailable"]}]];
```

The list:

```
class // EntityList;
```

Comment: The documentation indicates that the Contains functions should work: `EntityList[
 EntityClass["MusicWork", {"FirstReleaseDate" -> DateObject[{1950}, "Year", "Gregorian", -6.`], 
   "Composers" -> ContainsNone[{Entity["Person", "NatKingCole::5czsz"], Entity["Person", ColePorter::44j37"]}]}]]`. Your highlighting of an experimental function makes me think this issue is still a work in progress at WRI.

Comment: @bobthechemist thank you i checked the documentation and indeed according to the Details section it should work. I am not sure why it would not.

Comment: I removed what I said about specifying properties with operators and specified that the functions are experimental thank you  for the correction.